# Boolean Expression Simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

[image]

Dear all,
I need help to simplify this Boolean algebra. Please give me a answer step by step.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**The SE is not for providing answers to your homework problems.
Please add what is your problem and where you got struck the next time**

*Coming to the solution:*

$(abc + ab'c + a'bc +a'b'c+a'bc'+abc')$

$=c[ab + ab'+ a'b + a'b'] + c'[a'b+ab]$

$=c[1] + c'[b(a+a')]$

$=c + c'b$

$=c + b    (absorption law).

This is what you need

Comment: Just mark the answer as correct if it correct, or vote up if the answer is useful. No need to say thanks.

Comment: The c' term is redundant because of c, so = c + b is the final answer.